# ActiveRecord format joins into an array

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to improve the efficiency of one of my endpoints. Here's the rundown:

In a mysql database, we have three example tables, two of which are join tables to the first.

```rb
:user has_many: :orders 
:user has_many: :attributes
```

The sequel query is simple (but subject to change):

```rb
User.left_joins(:orders, :attributes).select("users.*, orders.*, attributes.*")
```

This query returns big objects, for every user, an order or attribute where it exists, it returns a flat object.

```rb
[
  {
    User:
     id: 1,
     order_id: 1,
     order_columns_here,
     attribute_id: 1,
     attribute_columns_here
  },
  {
    User:
     id: 1,
     order_id: 2,
     order_columns_here,
     attribute_id: 2,
     attribute_columns_here
  }
]
```

The result is an array of the same user data repeated multiple times for every order or attribute associated to it.

If I have to write some ruby to format this object the way the API is requested, its going to be slow (we have a huge db). Is there an active record method that I can use to augment this query so the data is returned with all the photos and floor_plans in an array?

i.e.

```rb
[
  {
    User: id: 1, orders: [all_order_data_for_user_1], attributes: [all_attributes_data_for_user_1]
  }
]
```

The last couple years I've been using the Sequel gem, which does this for me. I've read through much of the AR docs, and am not sure what would help me here from the ActiveRecord world.

Any ideas?

*EDIT*

Mysql version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.29
Rails: 5
Ruby: 2.3.1

Comment: How are you going to use the result?
You can use `.includes` instead of `.left_joins`, it will preload the relations.

Answer (score 0):

If you know up front that you will be using both the assocations you can use `.eager_load` which will load all the assocatiated items in one query:

```
User.eager_load(:orders, :attributes)
```

If you don't quite know you can use its indecisive twin `.includes` which tries to be smart and can create one two queries depending on how its used, which way the wind is blowing and the phase of the moon.

This lets you iterate though the records and call the assocation without creating n+1 queries:

```
User.eager_load(:orders, :attributes).each |user|
  puts user.order.inspect
end
```

But you would usually pass the data to a serializer or jbuilder template for formatting.

See: [Preload, Eagerload, Includes and Joins](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html)